# Loop Visible Rows after filter & Copy to another Sheet base on Condition

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to copy all visible rows from sheet1 table1 to sheet2 table2 after filter if Column B is empty. The code I have below only copy the last data to the other sheet and it will copy to the rest of the table.

```
Sub Send()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim visRng As Range ' Creating a range variable to store our table, excluding any rows that are filtered out.

Set wsCopy = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDest1 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

MsgBox "Sending Form...."

Set visRng = Range("Table1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'Check all visible Rows in Table1

Dim r As Range

For Each r In visRng.Rows ' Loop through each row in our visible range ...
  'MsgBox (r.Row) ' ... and retrieve the "absolute" row number.

 If wsCopy.Cells(r.Row, 2).Value = "" Then
  wsCopy.Range("A" & r.Row).Copy 
  wsDest1.Range("Table2").Columns(1).PasteSpecial
 End If

 Next

End Sub
```

here is sample filter in [Sheet1 Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FYZw.png)

here is the result of my code in [Sheet2 Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaHb1.png)

Expected Result: [Sheet2 Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJsWP.png)

Comment: What data do you wat to copy exactly? Because the two tables have diffent headers.

Comment: data from column A @EvilBlueMonkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub Send()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
'IN THE CODE wsDest WAS CALLED wsDest1. I CHANGED THE REFERENCES IN THE CODE. I'D SUGGET YOU TO USE Option Explicit.
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim visRng As Range ' Creating a range variable to store our table, excluding any rows that are filtered out.
'ADDED A NEW VARIABLE
    Dim DblRow As Double
    
    Set wsCopy = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    MsgBox "Sending Form...."
'CHANGED visRng TO TARGET ONLY THE FIRST COLUMN OF Table1. NO NEED TO INCLUDE THE REST OF THE TABLE; IT WOULD ONLY MAKE OUR EXECUTION LONGER
    Set visRng = Range("Table1").Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'Check all visible Rows in Table1
'YOU SHOULD PUT THIS DECLARATION AT THE BEGINNING. ALSO I'D SUGGEST NOT TO USE A SINGLE LETTER VARIABLE. wsDest IS A GOOD NAME FOR A VARIABLE.
    Dim r As Range
'SETTING THE VARIABLE.
    DblRow = 1
    
    For Each r In visRng.Rows ' Loop through each row in our visible range ...
        'MsgBox (r.Row) ' ... and retrieve the "absolute" row number.
        
        If wsCopy.Cells(r.Row, 2).Value = "" Then
            wsCopy.Range("A" & r.Row).Copy
'YOUR CODE DIDN'T SCROLL THE TABLE 2. USING DBLROW IN .Cells YOU CAN DO IT.
            wsDest.Range("Table2").Cells(DblRow, 1).PasteSpecial
            DblRow = DblRow + 1
        End If
        
    Next

End Sub
```

Edits highlighted by proper comments.

Report any question you have or bug you have encountered. If, according to your judgment, this answer (or any other) is the best solution to your problem you have the privilege to accept it ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).